ROS 2 Humble Velodyne VLP-16 LiDAR not outputting any data
I am attempting to use the Velodyne VLP-16 LiDAR sensor in ROS 2 Humble. I'm using an Nvidia Jetson Orin Nano running JetPack 6.1, which is based on Ubuntu 22.04. The goal is to use the LiDAR for SLAM navigation, but for now I've just been trying to get the ros-drivers/velodyne set of packages to work.
After following the steps on this wiki (with commands adjusted for ROS 2) I can get all the nodes to run, but cannot see any data coming from the VLP-16 when echoing the velodyne_points topic or in RViz.
Here are troubleshooting steps I've taken to rule out potential issues:

Verified that the VLP-16 works as expected on a Windows computer and outputs data in the Veloview software (this should rule out a hardware issue)
Successfully pinged the IP address of the VLP-16 while it is connected to the Jetson (192.168.50.200)
Updated the config file in the velodyne_driver package with the correct IP address and port number (192.168.50.200, port: 2368)
Assigned a static IP address to the VLP-16.
Set the IP address of the Jetson to 192.168.50.202
Set the netmask to 255.255.255.0 and the gateway to 0.0.0.0
Enabled port forwarding for the 2368 port
Tried several other IP addresses for both the VLP-16 and the Jetson
Used the humble-devel branch and the ros2 branch when pulling the Velodyne packages from github
Successfully built the ROS 2 workspace with colcon build
Verified that all nodes and topics expected from the Velodyne packages run as expected
Used the ros2 launch velodyne velodyne-all-nodes-VLP16-launch.py command to run all nodes
Re-flashed the Jetson Orin Nano
Reinstalled ROS Humble

Even after all these steps (and probably some I'm forgetting) I have not gotten the VLP-16 to output so much as a single data point in ROS 2, even though everything appears to be working. I've seen a few existing forum posts with this issue, but all the ones with answers suggested some combination of the above steps and did not solve my issue.
Any advice regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I left out any important information and I'll update my question.
Thank you!

Welcome to Robotics, ScienceKeanu. Are you sure the lidar is functioning as expected? There is a set of steps here that describe testing with WireShark and VeloView to test a connection to the device. Please try these steps and see if you can display points with VeloView.

Hi Chuck, thanks! As I mentioned in my post, I have confirmed that the lidar displays points in VeloView and confirmed that the lidar is showing up at the expected IP address.

Ack sorry, not sure how I missed that. In the repo it looks like the model config defaults to VLP16, but the documentation says it defaults to 64E. What do you get if you run ros2 node list or ros2 topic list?

When I run ros2 node list I get: /velodyne_driver_node, /velodyne_laserscan_node, /velodyne_transform_node. Running ros2 topic list I get: /diagnostics, /parameter_events, /rosout, /scan, /velodyne_packets, /velodyne_points.
